# Sum of Cauchy sequences is Cauchy in an Abelian Topological Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a topological abelian group and suppose $0$ has a countable
fundamental system of neighborhoods. Let $(x_n),(y_n)$ be Cauchy sequences
of $G$. Why is it true that $(x_n+y_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence?

I tried to generalize the case of real sequences: my problem is that if
$U$ is a neighborhood of $0$, then i would need to use something like
$\frac{1}{2} U$, but obviously this does not make sense.

I also looked at this relevant question 
[Sum of Cauchy Sequences Cauchy?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84854/sum-of-cauchy-sequences-cauchy)
however it was not very helpful, since it refers to metric topological groups.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, every first countable Hausdorff topological group has a compatible metric by the [Birkhoff-Kakutani theorem](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/05/17/the-birkhoff-kakutani-theorem/)... More seriously: replace $\frac{1}{2}U$ by an open set $V$ such that $0 \in V$ and $V+V \subset U$. To find such a set $V$ use continuity of addition.

Comment: @t.b. Hahaha...Ok, i am gonna try this, looks interesting :-)

Comment: But now what about the title question, possibly non-abelian?  Now you have to specify left-Cauchy or right-Cauchy ... and then what?

Comment: @GEdgar: Its abelian, i will fix it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You had the right idea, so let me spell out the argument with the fix I suggested in the comments:

Suppose that for every $0$-neighborhood $U$ there is a $0$-neighborhood $V$ such that $V + V \subset U$. Since $(x_n)$, and $(y_n)$ are Cauchy, there is $N$ such that $x_n - x_m \in V$ and $y_n - y_m \in V$ for all $m,n \geq N$ and hence $(x_n+y_n)-(x_m+y_m) = (x_n-x_m)+(y_n-y_m) \in V+V \subset U$ for all $m,n \geq N$, showing that $(x_n+y_n)$ is Cauchy.

To see that our hypothesis is in fact true, we can argue as follows: Since the addition map $a\colon G \times G \to G, (g,h) \mapsto g+h$ is continuous, we know that $a^{-1}(U) \subset G \times G$ is open. Also, $(0,0) \in a^{-1}(U)$, so there are open $0$-neighborhoods $V_1, V_2 \subset G$ such that $V_1 \times V_2 \subset a^{-1}(U)$ by the definition of the product topology. Now $V = V_1 \cap V_2$ is a $0$-neighborhood such that $V + V \subset U$, since $V \times V \subset V_1 \times V_2 \subset a^{-1}(U)$.