# Sum of Cauchy sequences in an abelian topological group (first countability hypothesis)

Tags: general-topology, analysis, topological-groups

We know that, given a **first countable** abelian topological group $G$, the sum of two Cauchy sequences gives yet another Cauchy sequence (see, e.g., [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/191488/59556)).

For those wondering, we say that a sequence $(x_n)$ in $G$ is Cauchy if for any neighborhood $U$ of $0$, there exists an integer $s = s(U)$ such that $x_n - x_m \in U$ whenever $n,m \geq s$.

However, I don't see where the countability hypothesis is used. <strike>I know that it is required, as there exist counterexamples (take $G = \mathbb{R}$ with the metric $d(x,y) = |\arctan(x)-\arctan(y)|$ and the Cauchy sequences $(x_n),(y_n)$ with $x_n = n, \, y_n = (-1)^n - n$)</strike> (This is actually first-countable, as a metric space).

***Update***: I am essentially wondering **why** Atiyah-Macdonald restrict themselves to groups where $0$ has a countable neighborhood basis when talking about these concepts. Let's include a picture:

[image: Picture]

Can anyone enlighten me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you define a Cauchy sequence in an arbitrary topological space?

Comment: @AsafKaragila see my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, first countable is not needed for the Cauchyness of sum of Cauchy sequences, the [given proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191467/sum-of-cauchy-sequences-is-cauchy-in-an-abelian-topological-group/191488#191488) uses only that for each open neighborhood $U$ there is a $V$ such that $V+V\subseteq U$, which is basically the continuity of addition.

Instead, your counterexample is rather tricky! They are Cauchy sequences with respect to the given metric, but they are *not Cauchy* as defined from the topological group structure (I guess the usual addition is used)..

Anyway, $\Bbb R$ is first countable.

Comment: By definition of the uniform structure on an *abelian* group, $(x,y) \mapsto x-y$ and $y \mapsto -y$ are uniformly continuous, hence so is $(x,y) \mapsto x+y$. Uniformly continuous functions preserve Cauchy-sequences/nets/filters.

Comment: @Martin Okay, this is really confusing to me. Is there any reason why Atiyah-Macdonald restrict themselves to topological groups where $0$ admits a countable neighborhood basis when defining these concepts? I thought this was the reason but apparently I'm wrong.

Comment: I also see why my "counterexample" is silly, since any metric space is first countable...

Comment: @AlexP. The reason is that they later want to describe the *completion* using sequences, I think. The completion of a general topological group is a bit of a mess.

Comment: @Martin I included the relevant picture in my original post. I really don't see where the first countability hypothesis simplifies anything, though. We can simply define the completion as the set of equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences.

Comment: @AlexP. Yes, I think you can give a meaningful definition for every topological abelian group, as you suggested. The resulting group should be sequentially complete (I haven't checked). However, *completeness* of a uniform space is a stronger requirement than just *sequential* completeness. Probably their choice is a mixture of two things: avoid technicalities with uniform spaces and cover the interesting situations for the applications they have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why Atiyah and MacDonald restrict to first-countable topological abelian groups is because otherwise to construct the completion one would need to use the [theory of filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filters_in_topology) (and other things I haven't ever studied, see Bourbaki, *General Topology*, Chap. III, §3), in which case it is “a bit of a mess,” as Martin said on a comment in Berci's answer.

One leverages the first-countability property to allow $\hat{G}$ to be set-theoretically described as the set of Cauchy sequences in $G$ modulo the equivalence relation stated on the screenshot from the OP. If you want to see the first-countability hypothesis in action, one actually needs to invoke it to show that

1. $\hat{G}$ has a well-defined topology (see proof of Lemma 3 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4764540/394668)),
2. the sum $\hat{G}\times\hat{G}\to\hat{G}$ is continuous (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4762701/394668)),
3. if $A$ a first-countable topological ring, then the product $\hat{A}\times\hat{A}\to\hat{A}$ is well-defined and it is continuous (see Lemmas 3 and 5 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4768444/394668)), and
4. the scalar product $\hat{A}\times\hat{M}\to\hat{M}$ is well-defined and it is continuous, for $M$ a first-countable topological $A$-module (see ibid., Lemmas 8, 9 and 10).

All these four facts are left unproven by Atiyah, MacDonald.