# Is it possible to show that the addition of two Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb R^n$ is also Cauchy for any metric?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

A problem in my homework asks to show that the addition of two Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb R^n$ is also Cauchy. However, the metric is not specified. If we assume that we are dealing with the [euclidean metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) then the problem is relatively straightforward. However, when attempting to solve without this assumption, one needs to show for Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb R^n$ being $x_n$ and $y_n$ that  $\forall \epsilon >0 \exists N \in \mathbb N$ such that $\forall l,k \ge N$ $$d(\mathbf x_l +\mathbf y_l, \mathbf x_k +\mathbf y_k) < \epsilon  $$ Is it possible to show this? If so, hints on how to start would be appreciated.

Comment: If they don't specify which metric, they surely mean the standard metric.

Comment: This is, in general, not true, as shown in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84854/sum-of-cauchy-sequences-cauchy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. $\;\;\;\;$ $\langle -1,\hspace{-0.04 in}-2,\hspace{-0.04 in}-3,\hspace{-0.04 in}-4,\hspace{-0.04 in}-5,\hspace{-0.04 in}-6,\hspace{-0.04 in}-7,\hspace{-0.04 in}-8,...\rangle\:$ and $\:\langle 0,\hspace{-0.03 in}2\hspace{.02 in},\hspace{-0.03 in}2\hspace{.02 in},\hspace{-0.04 in}4,\hspace{-0.04 in}4,\hspace{-0.04 in}6\hspace{.02 in},\hspace{-0.03 in}6,\hspace{-0.03 in}8,...\rangle$

are both  Cauchy with respect to the metric $\;\; \langle x\hspace{.02 in},\hspace{-0.03 in}y\rangle \: \mapsto \hspace{-0.05 in} \left|\hspace{.02 in}\operatorname{arctan}(x)\hspace{-0.03 in}-\hspace{-0.02 in}\operatorname{arctan}(\hspace{.03 in}y)\right| \;\;$,

but their sum is $\: \langle -1,\hspace{-0.04 in}0,\hspace{-0.04 in}-1,\hspace{-0.04 in}0,\hspace{-0.04 in}-1,\hspace{-0.04 in}0,\hspace{-0.04 in}-1,\hspace{-0.04 in}0,\hspace{-0.04 in}-1,\hspace{-0.04 in}0\rangle\:$, $\;$ which is not Cauchy with respect to *any* metric.